# Live Activities created but not visible in notification center

Tags: ios, widgetliveactivity

I've implemented the live activities, and getting no issues so far. It's getting created, but is not visible in notification center, and no error is being thrown

I'm using `XCode 15.0 beta 8` and testing on real device `iOS 17.0`

Below is my `NotificationLiveActivity.swift` file

```swift
import ActivityKit
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct NotificationAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        var title: String
        var label: String
    }
    
    var id: String
}

@available(iOS 16.2, *)
struct NotificationLiveActivity: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(for: NotificationAttributes.self) { context in
            Text(context.state.title)
        } dynamicIsland: { context in
            DynamicIsland {
                // Expanded UI goes here.  Compose the expanded UI through
                // various regions, like leading/trailing/center/bottom
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading) {
                    Text(context.state.title)
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.trailing) {
                    Text(context.state.label)
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
                    Text(context.state.title)
                }
            } compactLeading: {
                Text(context.state.title)
            } compactTrailing: {
                Text(context.state.label)
            } minimal: {
                Text(context.state.title)
            }
            .widgetURL(URL(string: "http://www.apple.com"))
            .keylineTint(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the snippet where activity is created:**

```swift
func startLiveActivity(title: String, label: String) {
        let attributes = NotificationAttributes(id: "")
        let state = NotificationAttributes.ContentState(
            title: title, label: label
        )
        do {
            stopwatchActivity = try Activity<NotificationAttributes>.request(
                attributes: attributes, contentState: state, pushType: nil)
            NSLog("activity id: \(stopwatchActivity?.id ?? "")")
            
            NSLog("description: \(stopwatchActivity?.content.description ?? "")")
        } catch(let e) {
            NSLog("error: \(e)")
        }
    }
```

**Logs screenshot:**

[image: Logs screenshot]

It's expected to show live activity in notification center

Comment: Do you have a widget extension target with other widgets? If so try to bring the live activity widget to a new / different target.

Comment: @Timo thanx for looking into it, I got it working by changing some settings in xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unchecking `Copy only when installing` fixed the issue

[image]

Update 1:

If the above solution doesn't work, restart your iPhone

Answer (score 1):

I want to add something to what @iamdipanshus said, cause it worked for me, but I think we need to clarify where is that option/menu:

1. You should tap on your project (normally top left corner), a new tab will appear: your_project.xcodeproj
2. Select the target that points to your whole app (NOT the widget target).
3. Then get into the "Build Phases" tab on top of it.
4. Scroll until you see the menu that @iamdipanshus uploaded.
5. Uncheck the option "Copy only when installing".
   Hope it helps! Took me some time to figure out where it was!